# Is an aluminum foil wrap working as a shield in my spliced USB cable?

Tags: usb, soldering, shielding

I'm preparing to cut apart a non-trivial $ device and try to extend a 4-conductor cable, so I have been practicing my splicing skills. I figured a USB cable would be a good test.

I spliced, heat-shrink-insulated each solder splice and also soldered the ground wire. I wanted to see if the thing would actually transmit data once I was done, so I tried to get the original foil shield re-wrapped around the splices, but of course they wouldn't quite go.

I figured I could get a connected layer of aluminum around that spot fairly easily if I wrapped the works with some aluminum foil from the kitchen. I had foil on foil on ground wire, squeezed it tight, then heat-shrink wrapped the whole thing. It seems to charge fine right around 5 volts, and plugging my Anrdoid phone into my PC, the data flow seems good too. I ran some file operations on the phone from the PC and copied a few folders of music for a minor test.

I'm curious if that aluminum foil is working as a shield or if  shielding not that big a deal in such conditions.

Is an aluminum foil wrap working as a shield in my spliced USB cable?

Comment: It probably is helping, although not as much as a real shield would.  Generally, it would work best to replace the shorter length of cable entirely with a longer length.  In a pinch, consider [conductive-adhesive copper foil tape](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=conductive+adhesive+copper+tape&t=opera&ia=web) for better shielding.

Comment: It's better than nothing, but not anywhere near as good as a well designed, and terminated, shield.  Even a small hole can play havoc with the shielding effectiveness, as can a pig-tailed shield termination.

Comment: Keep in mind that USB cable has the signal wires (green/white) twisted. If your 4-wire interface has independent signaling, the tightly-coupled green-white wires will have substantial cross-talk, such that a heavy signal interference will occur, and the interface might fail or work unreliably.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminium foil can act as decent shield, many cables use coiled foil wraps around conductors for shields. The coiled foil wraps are typically not as good as a braid or solid conductor.

Aluminum's skindepth for 0.1mm goes to almost 1GHz so even a thin foil will conduct high frequencies.

However, on a digital signal, a shield probably isn't going to do much for a few cm of wire.

Also make sure you make a good connection between old and new shield.

Comment: The foil is typically grounded by being in contact with a drain (ground) wire.

Comment: Depends on the implementation by the OP, many shields are grounded only on one end

Comment: Many shields?  How 'bout some shields?  I can't think of the last system I worked on that had a shield only grounded the one end, all of these being RF/GHz/high speed digital boxes and systems.

Comment: For building scale fire alarm systems single ended termination is normal.  Doesn't a double terminated shield require special treatment because of the loop created?

Comment: Yes, but in some applications a ground loop can be tolerated.

Comment: Thanks. Mine was wrapped tight against the ground wire, which was soldered so it remained contiguous the length of the usb cable. No idea if it was properly terminated at both ends as it was an old phone OEM cord.

Comment: my hdmi cable was getting interferance, I put a couple of laps of aluminum foil around it and now it works perfectly, it's not even grounded